# Оптимизация SELECT со статистикой

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(`count`) AS 'visits', `code`
FROM `om_log`
WHERE `code` <> '0'
    AND `date` >='1464728400'
    AND `date` <='1467320399'
GROUP BY `code`
ORDER BY `code`;
```

В таблице записей очень много, это статистика посещения сайта. Обычно она собирается за месяц. Есть идеи как оптимизировать данный запрос, не прибегая к рефакторингу и использованию промежуточных таблиц с счетчиками?

EXPLAIN:

```
id | select_type | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | range | "code,date"   | date | 5       | NULL | 1420 | "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

Comment: А индекс по колонке date есть ? И когда речь заходит об оптимизации первым делом надо смотреть и приводить здесь план выполнения запроса (получаемый по explain)

Comment: Индексы есть, только поле `count` не проиндексировано, но при попытке добавить к нему индекс локальный MySQL рухнул. Количество записей сейчас 9 049 853, explain сейчас добавлю.

Comment: а зачем вам поле count. сделайте count(1) он даст тот же результат, если поле count у вас везде не NULL

Comment: @Mike, А с чего вы взяли что в `count` будут всегда иденицы?

Comment: но вы же используете функцию count() которая считает _количество_ not null значений и ей плевать какре именно значение в колонке count. если бы вы ожидали в этой колонке разные значения то наверное вы использовали бы sum()

Comment: @Mike Большое спасибо. Чего то не подумал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данную оптимизацию может зделать MySQL вместо меня с помощью механизма партиционирования. Это физическое разделение файла таблицы на несколько по определенному признаку. Таким образом запросы начинают выполнятся в разы быстрее. Главное не переусердствовать с их количеством.

```
ALTER TABLE `om_log`
PARTITION BY RANGE(date)
PARTITIONS 6(
    PARTITION less2015      VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01')),
    PARTITION less2016      VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01')),
    PARTITION less2017      VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01')),
    PARTITION less2018      VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01')),
    PARTITION less2019      VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01')),
    PARTITION other         VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Сейчас я сделал их с запасом, но похорошому не плохо добавлять партиции кроном при необходимости, например в конце года, а партицию 5летней давности допустим удалять.

**Сделать партиционирование существующей таблицы, которая активно используется невозможно,** возникает блокировка таблицы и это ложит сайт. Необходимо создавать новую таблицу, на которую переключать работу сайта, а после переносить небольшими порциями все записи туда.

**Сейчас решена задача добавлениям комбинированных индексов!** Скорость запросов 2-5 сек. Это более менее приемлемое время вместо бывших 90сек.

Answer (score 1):

С ключами так понимаю всё ок. Путей много:

1. Сборка кластера - мой лайк за Percona XtraDB Cluster DB кластер и за MariaDB Galera Cluster. Перкона - стабильнее, мария - умнее, может уже и пофиксили траблы стабильности.
2. Шардинг - бьём одну БД на несколько, которые крутятся на разных серверах. Шардингом нужно управлять из кода - это непростая штука.
3. Партицианирование - можно, но у него предел бонуса тоже имеется.
4. Отказ от SQL в пользу nosql решений: гораздо более простое масштабирование, быстрее на большом количестве записей.

Вообще оптимизация и масштабирование БД - это целая большая интересная область IT.

Comment: 1,2,4 - решения мне кажатся выстрелом из пушки по воробьям из пушки.
1 - Собирать целые кластера ради одной таблицы, которая когда то да подчистится, разве 10мил. записей проблема для MySQL? 
2 - Вы и сами уточнили что это не простая штука, опять таки для 10 мил. записей то...
4 - Перепилить всю базу и все запросы? Потратить уйму времени, это хоть окупится?

Аргументируйте если есть конкретные мнения по поводу их прменений.

Comment: - Перепилить всю базу и все запросы? - Ну тут как сказать - если юзаем ORM, например доктрину: адаптер БД меняется в одну строчку.   Все решения я запостил для серьёзных проектов - где большие толстые БД, где куча пользователей, там если всплыла одна трабла с нагрузкой, тут же всплывает и другая. Эти решения позволяют сделать масштабируемость - то есть простое повышение производительности линейными затратами.
-разве 10мил. записей проблема для MySQL
Большая проблема, особенно если хочется сложных выборок(фильтров), поиск по тексту.

Comment: к сожелению БД, да и сам проект слехка в запущенном состоянии (20 лет без полного рефакторинга, только мелкий). По этому дыры сейчас нужно затыкать, а при рефакторинге когда на него дадут время (может когда все сломается вовсе), тогда и учтем и архитектуру продумаем.